# How to fix a leaking cold/hot water faucet

Tags: repair, faucet, valve

Our hot water faucet has been leaking (on its own, and also when the cold water faucet is turned on). Our building technician diagnosed a problem with the valves and recommended that we replace both the hot and cold water faucet assembly with Kohler [GP77005-RP CW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GZON4C) and [GP77006-RP Kohler CCW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GZVOH6) valve kits:

[image: Picture of valve]

I have been trying to figure out some installation instructions for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Before the below links work, you'll need to create a new session by clicking on this, [**Kohler Help Topics***](http://helptopics.us.kohler.com)

See if below [Knowledge Base](http://helptopics.us.kohler.com/ics/support/KBSplash.asp) articles from Kohler help:

- [How Do I Replace The Valve On My Single Control Faucet?](http://helptopics.us.kohler.com/ics/support/KBAnswer.asp?questionID=559)
- [How Do I Replace The Seals On My Single Control Kitchen Faucet?](http://helptopics.us.kohler.com/ics/support/KBAnswer.asp?questionID=561)
- [How Do I Change The Valves In My Two Handle Faucet?](http://helptopics.us.kohler.com/ics/support/KBAnswer.asp?questionID=565)

**Hat-tip to "[BMitch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/2196/bmitch)" for the heads-up on the "new session" requirement.*

Comment: Note that before these links will work, you have to create a new session by clicking on this: http://helptopics.us.kohler.com/

Comment: @BMitch +1 for the heads-up :)

Comment: awesome! thanks for the knowledge base resource.

Answer (score 4):

Step one: purchase the appropriate valve for your sink.

Step two: read the instructions that come with the valve. :)

Sorry, I couldn't resist.  Turn the water off to the sink first.  The faucet may have a cap that can be removed, either via a small screw in a difficult to see place (behind or when you lift the handle all open) or the cap is friction fit you can pop it off with a putty knife.  My best guess looking at this valve and because it's for separate hot/cold handles is that the cap is on the very top of the handle.  From there, you can remove the handle, usually with a screw or two.  Unscrewed, it should come right off.

And then the cartridge/valve is removed by unscrewing it.  However, this is the tricky part, and the one that took me the longest time to figure out.  At least until I got the replacement valve that included an adapter to unscrew the old and install the new valve (buying the valve first would have saved me an hour).

Before you install the new one, check if the instructions tell you to lubricate the o-rings.  If they don't specify what kind of lubricant, I think Vaseline is safe, though I've been known to use some chapstick in a pinch.  You should also clean out the hole in the sink as best you can, using an old toothbrush or whatever else you can get in there and not lose.  After that, you just reverse the steps you took to get everything apart.

Comment: Seeing how I wasted an hour in the past trying to get the old valve out (because I wanted to have it when shopping for the replacement), I can understand the questioner's challenge.  Sadly, that little extractor is needed and comes with the replacement valve.  Good old catch-22.

Comment: I will note that mine was a single handle Delta, so it may be a little different.  And it's hard to tell in the pic, but you may be able to extract that with a simple socket wrench, and if so, thumbs up to Kohler for a better design.

Comment: i appreciate the extra tips that the knowledge base didn't mention wrt greasing. now only if se were to let me accept 2 answers ;)

Comment: IMPORTANT:  Plug the drain hole before doing anything.  Screws and other small parts like to hide in the trap.

Comment: @rs79, no worries, you asked for instructions and Mike pointed you right to them.  His is the right answer IMO.