# How can I fix a faucet handle that is leaking?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a kohler faucet and the faucet handle itself (the thing you turn) is leaking a bit when only that side (cold) is on. How can I diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a leaking cold/hot water faucet](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/how-to-fix-a-leaking-cold-hot-water-faucet)

Comment: Thanks. So your best guess is that it's a faulty valve?